# Getting Uncaught TypeError when using var with .play() method in Howler.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, howler.js

I am using howler.js to launch audio when hovering over elements on the page.  To avoid duplicating the hover function for each element I figured I could just grab the id of each element, store the result in a variable and use that variable to play the corresponding audio track.  The variable "track" returns the correct result in the console but when I attach it to the .play() method I get...

> Uncaught TypeError: track.play is not a function 
>       (anonymous function) @ index.html:413 
>       b.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3 
>       v.handle @jquery.min.js:3

Here's the code (using jquery 1.9.1 and howl.js 1.1.26)

```js
var One   = new Howl({ urls: [ 'audio/One.mp3' ] });
var Two   = new Howl({ urls: [ 'audio/02.mp3' ] });
var Three = new Howl({ urls: [ 'audio/03.mp3' ] });

$('.track').hover(function() {
  var track = $(this).attr("id");
  track.play();
  console.log(track);
}, function() {
  var track = $(this).attr("id");
  track.pause();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/1.1.26/howler.min.js"></script>

<div class="track" id="One">Track 1</div>
<div class="track" id="Two">Track 2</div>
<div class="track" id="Three">Track 3</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a string to reference a variable by name. The best way to handle this is going to be to create an object to hold your tracks.

```
var tracks = {
    One: new Howl({ urls: [ 'audio/One.mp3' ] }),
    Two: new Howl({ urls: [ 'audio/02.mp3' ] }),
    Three: new Howl({ urls: [ 'audio/03.mp3' ] })
};

$('.track').hover(function() {
    var track = $(this).attr("id");
    tracks[track].play();
    console.log(track);
}, function() {
    var track = $(this).attr("id");
    tracks[track].pause();
});
```

However, this is still not ideal. You could further improve it by using a data attribute to hold the track info, rather than the Id.

```
<div class="track" data-track="1">Track 1</div>
```

And then access it like this:

```
var track = $(this).data("track")
```

And then this way, you can store your tracks in an array, which is the most natural data type to use here:

```
var tracks = [
    new Howl({ urls: [ 'audio/One.mp3' ] }),    
    new Howl({ urls: [ 'audio/Two.mp3' ] })
];
```

Comment: If you already have the `id` from the hovered element... Why would you do twice the work. Shouldn't `$(this)` be enough? i.e. `$(this) === $("#" + $(this).attr("id"))`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl edited the var track part in the question... `$(this).attr('id')` returns "One" which is then stored in var track, at that point shouldn't `track.play() == One.play();` ?

Comment: @User No, that is the same as "One".play()

Comment: @User: You cannot use a variable name as a reference without scope. You might get away with `window[track].play();` which should be `window.One`, but I don't think this will work. Store your tracks in an object (map/namespace/whatever...) then access them.

Comment: @User: Also, variable names, when minimizing your code, change. Do not rely on the variable name you assign it. It is just to make it human readable.